# Jenkins Pipeline - Jenkins SCM step. Checkout returns invalid data not referring to parameters provided

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am setting up CI/CD for my project and decided to use Jenkins Pipeline. What I need basically:

1. Build from chosen branch(chosen from dropdown)
2. Execute some stages conditionally(depending on branch)

I configured pipeline to fetch Jenkinsfile from scm:
[image]
Then I decided to write cutom scm checkout as following:

```
stage('Checkout specific branch') {
        steps {
            echo "Checking out ${params.branchToBuild}..."
            script {
                def actualBranchCheckout = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
                                        branches: [
                                                [name: "${params.branchToBuild}"]
                                        ],
                                        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                                        extensions: [[$class: 'LocalBranch', localBranch: "**"]],
                                        submoduleCfg: [],
                                        userRemoteConfigs: [
                                                [credentialsId: "${env.REPO_SSH_CREDS_ID}", url: "${env.REPO_SSH_URL}"]
                                        ]
                ])
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have sveral concerns. GIT_ environment variables are set when checking out branch for Jenkinsfile.

```
GIT_BRANCH=origin/master
GIT_COMMIT=11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2, GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH=master, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT=11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2
```

That is fine, but when my checkout is performed the are not getting updated with actual values and remain the same.
Okay, the method itself returns map which may contain what I need so I can manually reset them, right?
But they turned out to be the same when checking out develop branch:

Here are the logs:

```
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Repo/repo_pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential jenkins-bitbucket
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git
 > git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Repo/repo_pipeline # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git # timeout=10
 > git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 31e727bf81b3379c9aa80224b8f941bc867acd77 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 31e727bf81b3379c9aa80224b8f941bc867acd77
Commit message: "print out variables"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Checkout specific branch)
[Pipeline] echo
Checking out develop...
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] checkout
using credential jenkins-bitbucket
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse origin/develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2 (origin/develop)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b develop 11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2
Commit message: "another try"
First time build. Skipping changelog.
[Pipeline] echo
[GIT_BRANCH:origin/master, GIT_COMMIT:31e727bf81b3379c9aa80224b8f941bc867acd77, GIT_LOCAL_BRANCH:master, GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT:11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2, GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT:11a5800b6ca31bc81545fa4874d73fa275c820c2, GIT_URL:git@bitbucket.org:team/repo.git]
```

I have another option to do everything manually, like `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` for branch and so on. Do anyone know how to solve this/ is it a known issue or I am doing something wrong way?

Comment: can you share a console log of the checkout ?

Comment: What is an argument you're passing to `echo`. Is it `actualBranchCheckout` ?

Comment: Yes, I pass the actualBranchCheckout. And somehow values are not what I expect them to be. Still no luck..

Comment: I found https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-45489. Looks pretty similar to what I experience..